# How to hide default labels on Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using `GoogleMapSDK v1.8` on my latest iOS app.
Is it possible to display a normal  map (`kGMSTypeNormal`) without any of the default labels?

For example, hiding some or all of the following: **city labels, road labels, public transport icons, etc**.
I hope there is a way to do this.
Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Hiding public transport icons would be especially useful, as rendering a duplicate icon on top purely for a marker which offers details and a 'get directions' option is particularly unattractive as they never line up perfectly.

Comment: This is possible now please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858621/1140335).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Google Maps SDK - Hide / remove labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032936/ios-google-maps-sdk-hide-remove-labels)

Answer (score 1):

> Map Types 
>   You can customize your map with one of several map types. A map's type governs the overall representation of the map. For example, an atlas usually contains political maps that focus on showing boundaries, and road maps that show all of the roads for a city or region. The Google Maps SDK for iOS offers the following types of maps:
>
> Type  Value   Description
>
> Normal kGMSTypeNormal Typical road map. Roads, some man-made features, and important natural features such as rivers are shown. Road and feature labels are also visible. This is the default map mode in Google Maps for iOS.
>
> Hybrid kGMSTypeHybrid Satellite photograph data with road maps added. Road and feature labels are also visible. This map type can be enabled on the Google Maps app for iOS by turning on the Satellite view.
>
> Satellite kGMSTypeSatellite   Satellite photograph data. Road and feature labels are not visible. This made is not available in Google Maps for iOS.
>
> Terrain   kGMSTypeTerrain Topographic data. The map includes colors,
>   contour lines and labels, and perspective shading. Some roads and
>   labels are also visible.
>
> None  kGMSTypeNone    No map tiles. The base map tiles will not be
>   rendered. This mode is useful in conjunction with tile layers. The
>   display of traffic data will be disabled when the map type is set to
>   none. Change the Map Type
>
> To set the type of a map, assign a new value to the GMSMapView.mapType
>   property. For example, to display a satellite map type:
>
> GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition
>   cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
>                                                           longitude:151.2086
>                                                                zoom:6]; mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
>   mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map

I believe that is a no and I found no api on the gmsmapview to hide them.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view

Comment: Can you share screenshot of how kGMSTypeNone map will look like?

Comment: kGMSTypeNone is literally a blank grey map. It looks quite cool after mapping all the London underground lines on a map.